# Need help understanding a posted algorithm (calculating step distance between hexagons on a grid)

Tags: java, algorithm, distance

I have been hunting for an answer on how to accurately calculate the distance between 2 hexagons on a hexagon grid as a number of hexs or "steps".

I came across this posting and it seems to be the correct solution as I have my hexagons setup exactly how Torben describes, however I am trying to figure out the algorithm he is proposing.  Specifically:

```
mydistance((x1,y1), (x2,y2))
     = if x1>x2 then mydistance((x2,y2), (x1,y1))
       else if y2>=y1 then x2-x1 + y2-y1
       else max(x2-x1, y1-y2)
```

I am pretty sure he is describing an algorithm however, I am getting lost on what he means by "mydistance((x2,y2), (x1,y1))" etc.  I figure he probably meant the formula for a distance between 2 points?  I tried that and its not working out :(  Furthermore, he says it on top before the = and that's just throwing me off.

Can anyone make an accurate idea what he means?

Thanks!!!

EDIT (IMPORTANT) ----  Here is an image of my hexagon grid pattern to shed some light:  Please visit
http://www.bart4president.com/test/hexGrid.jpg

Here is a clipping of the original posting below:

---

I prefer a numbering where both x and y correspond to straight lines
of hexes, i.e., letting x increase (with constant y) by going right
and y increase (with constant x) by going 60 degrees down from right
(assuming (0,0) is top left corner).

This way, if you move in one of the three "natural" directions, you
either have constant x, constant y or constant (x+y).

That makes calculation of distances etc. easier, as you don't have to
sepcial-case on odd and even rows.

I assume you know the hex coordinates and want to find the distance in
number of hexes while moving across edges.

If you had used the alternative numbering I described above, the
distance is calculated as follows:

```
mydistance((x1,y1), (x2,y2))
 = if x1>x2 then mydistance((x2,y2), (x1,y1))
   else if y2>=y1 then x2-x1 + y2-y1
   else max(x2-x1, y1-y2)
```

With the numbering shown on the webpage you sited, you can calculate
distance as follows:

```
yourdistance((x1,y1),(x2,y2))
 = mydistance((x1 - y1 `div` 2,y1), (x2 - y2 `div` 2,y2))
```

I.e., convert to the simpler coordinate system and calculate distance
in that.  You convert by subtracting half the y coordinate (rounded
down) from the x coordinate.

Torben

Comment: "To understand recursion, one must first understand recursion."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For comparison, here's my code for calculating the distance between two hexes:

```
/**
 *  Hex distance calculation
 */
public static int distance(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    int dx=x2-x1;
    int dy=y2-y1;

    if (dx*dy>0) {
        return Maths.abs(dx)+Maths.abs(dy);
    } else {
        return Maths.max(Maths.abs(dx),Maths.abs(dy));
    }
}
```

(x1,y1) and (x2,y2) are the co-ordinates of the two hexes you want to calculate the distance between. Note that these co-ordinates are not at right angles like they would be on a square grid: increasing x and increasing y are 60 degrees apart.

Comment: I'll give this a whirl.. standby!

Comment: P.S. If you want to use this directly then you probably need to convert `Maths` to `java.util.Math`: the above code is actually using a different maths library (but I think the functions are identical in this case).

Comment: got it Mikera.. however I think my grid might be setup a little differently.. it works in some cases.. but it doesn't in others.  Its hard to explain, but if I can't get this working then I'll post an image of how my board is setup.

Comment: Mikera have a look at http://www.bart4president.com/test/hexGrid.jpg  and see if your logic would line up?

Comment: If your x and y axes are 120 degrees apart then I think you can just swap the two branches of the if statement. If you have have staggered columns of hexes (i.e. x direction alternates between 60 and 120 degrees) then the formula gets much more complicated...

Comment: @Bart just seen your last comment with the hex grid. This is the "120 degrees" layout so I think you can just swap the if statement branches and it should work.

Comment: Mikera, yes, it does work to a certain degree just like you said.  However its not working when I move say.. down 3 and 1(up-left) from 3 down, it returns a distance of 1.  The same happens when I go up 3 and 1(down-right), it returns a distance of 1.

Comment: also.. if I go down 2, and 1(up-left), it returns a distance of 0.  Seems to be something missing from the algorithm to account for moving to some spaces.

Comment: ^^ yup exactly.. a staggered columns of hexes just like you said.. i'll have to look into this further.

Comment: Try changing the `Math.abs(dx+dy)` to `Math.abs(dx)+Math.abs(dy)`. I think this is another change that you need to make when switching to the 120 degrees format.

Answer (score 0):

In hexagonal coordinate system such that the y-axis was at a 60-degree angle to the x-axis. This avoids the odd-even row distinction. The distance in hexagonal coordinate system is:

```
dx = x1 - x0
dy = y1 - y0

if sign(dx) == sign(dy)
    abs(dx + dy)
else
    max(abs(dx), abs(dy))
```

You can convert `(x', y)` from your coordinate system to `(x, y)` in this one using:

```
x = x' - floor(y/2)
```

So `dx` becomes:

```
dx = x1' - x0' - floor(y1/2) + floor(y0/2)
```

Careful with rounding when implementing this using integer division. In Java for `int y` `floor(y/2)` is `(y%2 ? y-1 : y)/2`.

Comment: Pardon the noob question, but what do you mean by sign(dx) == sign(dy) .. specifically "sign" ?  Thanks for you reply.

Comment: Actually it appears you have the same formula as mikera gave me.  I think its just a problem of how I have my hexes set up.. have a look at: http://www.bart4president.com/test/hexGrid.jpg  for how I have it set up.  Thanks again!

Comment: it is literally the sign: `+ or -` :)

Answer (score 0):

You write:

> *I am pretty sure he is describing an algorithm however, I am getting
>   lost on what he means by "mydistance((x2,y2), (x1,y1))" etc. I figure
>   he probably meant the formula for a distance between 2 points?*

Just to pick up on that point, as the comment on your question hinted at but neither of the answers seems to have addressed:

The statement `mydistance((x2,y2), (x1,y1))` is a *recursive* call to the function that is being defined.  In this case, if the function is called with `x1>x2` then the function is called again with the points swapped.